# Laravel create table if doesn't exist on production environment

Tags: php, laravel

I need to use a database to store my sessions with Laravel 4, when the environment is set to production. When it's local the standard file drive system can be used.

I do not have access to the command line, so I'm unable to run any migrations, artisan commands (CloudFoundry setup). So my idea is that in my `app/start/global.php` file I'd add a check:

```
if (App::environment('production'))
{
    if(! Schema::hasTable( Config::get('session.table') )) {

        Schema::create( Config::get('session.table'), function($table)
        {
            $table->string('id')->unique();
            $table->text('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity');
        });

    }
}
```

If it's currently in production mode (this bit works), then check if there is a table with the name defined in my `app/config/session.php` file. If not, then create this table with that given name. I noticed the `hasTable` from the api (http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_hasTable).

However, when my app loads, I get the error:

`RuntimeException: PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'table_name.sessions' doesn't exist`

Is this because of the lifecycle of the app? How else could I do this...

Comment: This is probably because the session driver is loaded before your code that creates the table. Try moving that table creation code inside the session driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because the session starts before your `global.php` file is loaded. To be more descriptive, the session gets initiated in the `Illuminate\Session\Middleware` file within `handle` method and in the `handle` method you can see this:

```
if ($this->sessionConfigured())
{
    $session = $this->startSession($request);

    $request->setSession($session);
}
```

This happens during the boot process of the framework and after that the `$app->booted` is called where the `global.php` file gets included:

```
// Inside booted handler
$path = $app['path'].'/start/global.php';
if (file_exists($path)) require $path;
```

So, the `session table` is required before the `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\handle` gets called. You should create a `table` manually and if the environment is production then the table will be used otherwise it won't be used. So what's wrong if you keep a table in your `database` always ?

Also I'm thinking that, maybe you can create a custom `middleware` to do this dynamically but not sure whether it's a good idea or not.

Comment: Cheers for that makes sense. I decided to just create the table manually.. saves being fancy :)